# OpenOffice Calc: Counting unique strings in cell range

Tags: openoffice-calc

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the number of unique strings in a single column, excluding blank cells. So far I've seen solutions such as the following:

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(X2:X99;X2:X99))
```

Plus another similar formula using FREQUENCY instead of COUNTIF. However, applying this to my spreadsheet gives me a decimal value that has no apparent meaning. For example, if my column contains 20 cells containing "ABC", and 30 cells with "XYZ", I should have an output value of 2. However, this is not the case, and even I can clearly see that the above formula won't output anything larger than a 1, which has left me rather confused as to its usage.

Pivot tables seem to show the most promise, but I can't get that to work either. Here's what I tried:

- Select the column, including the header
- Select a new pivot table and use the selected range
- Drag the header from Available Fields to Row Fields
- Select the ignore empty rows option
- Create the table

This then creates a table with one row per unique entry in the first column, and an empty second column. One row below is a Total Result cell, with the adjacent cell empty.

From this, I can see that there must be some sort of capability of the software to find unique strings, so it would stand to reason that there must also be a way of counting them and displaying that value in a cell. The question is, how do I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Your first attempt should work if (a) wrapped in SUMPRODUCT and (b) the range does not contain blank cells:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(X2:X51;X2:X51))
```

Comment: That seems to work. Now is there a way to get blank cells ignored as well?

Comment: Not sure if that's a particularly elegant solution though. Is it not possible to have some sort of if(cell=null) type statement, and apply it to the range of cells?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I found the solution. =SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A500),"",1/COUNTIF(A1:A500,A1:A500))) looks like it's working.